# WebView Error in Android 4.0

Tags: android, webview, sd-card

I have made an app in which i am reading html file from sd card and displaying it in webview. That was running successfully in Android 3.2 but when i changed it to 4.0 and run there on Micromax tablet for testing. it is giving an error "The link may be temporarily down or it has moved to new address" Even It is not running in emulator also. can u tell me 4.0 doent support accessing files from SD card or what is the prob please suggest.

Code snippet is :

```
WebView webComp = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = webComp.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        

webComp.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());                    

    webComp.loadUrl("file://sdcard/Tab-Demo/index10.html");            
    } 
}

class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{ 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { 
        view.loadUrl (url); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of a ContentProvider to serve the local files to a WebView as shown over at:
http://blog.tourizo.com/2009/02/how-to-display-local-file-in-android.html

Change the overriden **openFile** to serve files with its root set to the SD Card

```
@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), uri.getPath());
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    return parcel;
}
```

With this method you can access the files with

```
webComp.loadUrl("content://Tab-Demo/index10.html");
```

Don't forget to add the ContentProvider to your manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the file path is the same on the tablet

Comment: does 4.0 takes different path then 3.2?? Because it is running succesfully in 3.2.

Comment: It's a best practice to get the path at run time instead of hard coding it as implementations can change from version to version or by vendors. Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() to get the root of the SD card.